# Bulk Insert Python SQL

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I've got an beautiful soup 4 script which scraps data from a website and then I'm wanting to bulk insert the contents of the scrapped data. Below is this script I've created however I'm wanting to tweak it so I can bulk insert the listoflists into my database (For Efficiency)

```
listoflists = []
x = 1
A_var = 11
B_var = 22
while x < 3:
    mlist = A_var, B_var
    listoflists.append(mlist)

    x = x + 1


print listoflists
print A_var
print B_var


cur_urls.execute ("""INSERT INTO test_table (ac, bc) VALUES (%s, %s);""",(A_var, B_var,))
conn_urls.commit()


cur_comp.close()
cur_urls.close()
conn_urls.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
listoflists = []
x = 1
A_var = 11
B_var = 22
while x < 3:
    mlist = A_var, B_var
    listoflists.append(mlist)

    x = x + 1


print listoflists #[(11,12),(11,12)] This is listOfTuple
print A_var #11
print B_var #12

for tup in listoflists:
    cur_urls.execute ("""INSERT INTO test_table (ac, bc) VALUES (%s, %s);""",(tup[0], tup[1]))

conn_urls.commit()


cur_comp.close()
cur_urls.close()
conn_urls.close()
```